# how to add image in sqlite database with c#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

i have a sqlite database file i want to know that how can an image be added in database using c# in WindowsFormsApplication.

i have used below code but it not working it says that **

> parameter is not valid at
>   system.drawing.imageconverter.fromstream(Stream stream , boolean use
>   EmbeddedColorManagement , Boolean ValidateImageData)

**

```
private void SelectAll_LockFolder_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = @"I:\Locked.png";

            //A stream of bytes that represnts the binary file
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            //The reader reads the binary data from the file stream
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

            //Bytes from the binary reader stored in BlobValue array
            byte[] BlobValue = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

            fs.Close();
            reader.Close();

            SQLiteConnection BlobsDatabaseConn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
            SQLiteCommand SaveBlobeCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
            SaveBlobeCommand.Connection = BlobsDatabaseConn;
            SaveBlobeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            string a = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            SaveBlobeCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Folders(FolderPath, Status) Values('" + a + "','" + BlobValue + "');";

            try
            {
                SaveBlobeCommand.Connection.Open();
                SaveBlobeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            finally
            {
                SaveBlobeCommand.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: are u sure this  code makes this error

Comment: yes ! i am sure

Comment: i am using a .PNG image to save into database but it shows nothing except this exception(error)